# Saving media like image and pdf in internal storage of android 13

Tags: java, android

I want to save image and pdf in new folder with my app name in my phone storage I am currently saving that in download folder because only there I can save both image and pdf and retrieve it but from there any user can see and delete that folder so I want to save in different folder not predefine public folder but i can't seem to find anything for android 13 can anyone help me?

i want to create new folder in store but only my app should have access to that folder and it can store both image and pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use getExternalFilesDir() fun to access to storage to make folder like this:

```
val appSpecificDirectory = getExternalFilesDir(null)
val newFolder = File(appSpecificDirectory, "YourAppNameFolder")
if (!newFolder.exists()) {
    newFolder.mkdirs()
}
val imageFile = File(newFolder, "example_image.jpg")
```

for this you should have permission to access to the storage in your app manifest and get from user in runtime.

Comment: No. For this app specific storage location you do not need any permission.

Comment: As per docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String) getExternalFilesDir "There is no security enforced with these files. For example, any application holding Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE can write to these files."  So can be accessed using apps with this and the Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like a sub folder under [getCacheDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getCacheDir()) might be a better fit to your needs. No permissions needed and only accessible to your app.

As you can see Google Files can access `getExternalFilesDir()` directory

[image]

Also from [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific)

> External storage directories: These directories include both a dedicated location for storing persistent files, and another location for storing cache data. Although it's possible for another app to access these directories if that app has the proper permissions

So with "proper permission" they can be accessed.

Comment: The user can clear the cache so this is not what is asked for.

Comment: @blackapps There is no perfect answer. Any where you put files the user can delete with factory reset, other locations like from `getExternalFilesDir` file manager apps like Google files can see/open/delete/edit and they are also available see/open/delete/edit via USB connection. At least with `getCacheDir` the files are not visible or editable or individually deletable.

Comment: Good answers are getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir(). They are perfect. And getExternalFilesDir() is not accessable by google Files app.

Comment: @blackapps getExternalFilesDir() is not good answer, it does not meet the criteria stated in the question of "but only my app should have access to that folder"

Comment: Name one other app that has access. And dont mention usb connection as that is too far from home and this question.

Comment: @blackapps Google Files which is built in to most phones can access getExternalFilesDir directory as shown in the picture I added to my answer. You mentioned clearing the cache, so via USB is not far from home if you go to that extreme of just being able to delete all files.

Comment: You posted a picture showing the Android directory. But now try to open the data directory there.

Comment: @blackapps updated the picture showing contents of a data directory as an example

Comment: Yes. But that is a picture made on an Android Q/10 device or with lower Android version. Since Android 11 this is not possible any more.

Comment: @blackapps No you are mistaken, that picture was taken from an API 33 (Android 13) emulator. Even the docs as referenced says External storage directories can be accessed with proper permission.

Comment: Please tell what these 'proper permissions' are. And now you are mixing up the whole stuff as with those 'External storage directories' getExternalFilesDir is not ment but getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() and the permission would be MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: And concerning your picture: we give no attention to emulators.

Comment: @blackapps Yes as per docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String) "To access paths belonging to other packages, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and/or Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are required. ". Just admit it for getExternalFilesDir you are wrong, I cannot be bothered to keep proving you are wrong.

Comment: No. There is more to do. If i meet you in town i buy you a beer and we will have a nice chat ;-).